# Temperature profile of a table with a hot tea mug on it?

Tags: thermal-conduction

When you place a hot mug of tea or coffee on a cool table, heat transfer causes the table surface's temperature (and what lies beneath that surface) to increase.

My question is: **what's the temperature profile** $T(x,y,z,t)$ **of the table below the hot cup?**

**Idealised:**

[image: mug on table]

For simplicity's sake the temperature of the cylinder is a constant ($T_0$) and the table has infinite dimensions in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions.

The steady state solution I believe to be trivial: given enough time ('infinity') everything  will end up at the same temperature ($T_0$).

Assuming no heat convection from the table to the  surrounding air, this is a wholly heat conduction problem and Fourier's Second Law can be applied:

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha \nabla^2 T}$$
where $T$ is a function of $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$. It may be better to adopt hemi-spherical coordinates though.

The heat transfer ($\dot{Q}$) from the hot cylinder to the cool table can be described with Newton:

$$\dot{Q(x,y)}=k\left[T_0-T(x,y)\right]$$

where $k$ is a heat transfer coefficient.

And this, sadly is about as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have a constant-temperature circular region on the surface of a semi-infinite medium or half-space.

Since you've precluded convection, there's no vertical heat transfer elsewhere at the surface. Therefore, via symmetry, the solution is the same as that for a constant-temperature circular region embedded within an *infinite* medium. This can be handy when looking up standard solutions.

If we assume temperature-independent material properties, we can superpose solutions. This can also be handy, as any finite area can be decomposed into points, and diffusion solutions for point sources may be readily found. (Good general references are Crank's *The Mathematics of Diffusion* and Carslaw's and Jaeger's *Conduction of Heat in Solids*. Note, however, that these references generally prioritize the single-input-pulse and constant-input-flux cases over the constant-boundary-constant case, whose transient response is more challenging to analyze.)

In this case, the problem you describe appears to be addressed in Norminton, E. J., and J. H. Blackwell. "[Transient heat flow from constant temperature spheroids and the thin circular disk](https://academic.oup.com/qjmam/article-abstract/17/1/65/1852552)." *The Quarterly Journal of Mechanics and applied mathematics* 17.1 (1964): 65-72, Blackwell, J. H. "[Transient heat flow from a thin circular disk—small-time solution](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F27A46FFC7FC71AE888BCA8E4A5C552B/S144678870001106Xa.pdf/div-class-title-transient-heat-flow-from-a-thin-circular-disk-small-time-solution-div.pdf)." *Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society* 14.4 (1972): 433-442, and Marder, B. M., and N. R. Keltner. "[Heat flow from a disk by separation of variables](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01495728108961806?casa_token=mYkaZZqv_zgAAAAA:u8rLgow7KI5IiU5mk9vTHVL8LT7h_IDqcyAA6bNvNNT6r34J4FHwU-sN4U8erNJnt7hLx51tHYoQ)." *Numerical Heat Transfer* 4.4 (1981): 485-497. The solutions are intricate and not reprinted here. See also Schneider et al.'s "[Transient thermal response of two bodies communicating through a small circular contact area](http://www.mhtl.uwaterloo.ca/pdf_papers/mhtl77-2.pdf)." *International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer* 20.4 (1977): 301-308.

As a simpler related example thoroughly reviewed by Crank and Carslaw & Jaeger, consider the one-time deposition of energy $Q$ on the surface of a semi-infinite medium. (This idealizes the thermal mass of the mug and its contents when set upon the surface.) The deposition location is taken as a point, which results in large errors within a few multiples of the mug radius but minimal error far from the mug, with the benefit of substantially simplifying the solution. The temperature distribution inside the medium is then

$$T(r,t)=\frac{Q}{4(\pi\alpha t)^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{4\alpha t}\right),$$

with temperature $T$, radial distance $r$, time $t$, and thermal diffusivity $\alpha$. But note that the final table temperature matches the initial temperature of the  table, not the mug, because of the assumption that the energy source is finite.

Comment: Looking at the OP’s last formula, you don’t have Dirichlet boundary conditions at the mug. There is no convection, but there still is a thermal contact conduction. You solution is only valid in the infinite $k$ limit.

Comment: None of them is my solution. Imperfect thermal contact is discussed in some articles cited by/citing Schneider et al. ([example](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981thph.confX....B/abstract)).

Comment: I was talking about your second paragraph but I get what you meant now.

Comment: Thanks very much!